# Is there a way to get an accepted input from a Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines

So say I build a Turing Machine that takes an input of 11(0|1)*0, as in only with that input will it end in an accepting state, is there any algorithms you know of to pull that accepted input from the Turing Machine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the theory of computation,not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem), this is impossible.